# Exibir zero a esquerda usando o método ToString

Tags: c#

Tenho mais ou menos o seguinte código implementado em c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Teste
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(0134.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Mas ele não exibe o int `0134` todo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O 0 a esquerda não está aparecendo.

Comment: Ja tentou "0134".ToString()?

Comment: Funciona mas queria converter int

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0134.ToString("D4");`

Dessa forma de algum modo deve passar quantos elementos existem no integer, se por exemplo sua integer for `00134`, não apareceria o primeiro elemento, seria necessário alterar D4 para D5

Comment: Obrigado funcionou.

Comment: Pode ver uma lista completa de parâmetros [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

### Forma Abreviada (Padrão)

**Formato:** `.ToString("D[n]")` ou `.ToString("d[n]")`

O **n** é opcional e quer dizer o tamanho da `string`, e caso o número não atinja o tamanho definido a `string` é completada com 0 a esquerda.

**Ex:**

```
  123.ToString("D");  //-> Saída: "123"
  123.ToString("D1"); //-> Saída: "123"
  123.ToString("D2"); //-> Saída: "123"
  123.ToString("D3"); //-> Saída: "123"
  123.ToString("D4"); //-> Saída: "0123"
  123.ToString("D5"); //-> Saída: "00123"
```

Fonte | [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

### Forma Explícita (Personalizada)

Há também a forma explícita, que é mais flexível e que dá para fazer a mesma coisa do que a forma abreviada.

**Ex:**

```
123.ToString("00000"); //-> Saída: "00123"
123.ToString("000");   //-> Saída: "123"
123.ToString("0-0-0"); //-> Saída: "1-2-3";
123.ToString("0-0");   //-> Saída: "12-0";
```

Fonte | [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)